# Generate a new class into a specific folder in Angular

Tags: angular, class, command-line

When I am trying to use `ng g class classname` and I am in the `folder` I want my `class` to be created, it still creates it outside the folder, in the `app folder` for instance.

What I read is that the previous way is the way to do, so do you know why it doesn´t work?

Comment: Have you tried to use ng g class ./classname?

Comment: if you are in the root folder or in the src folder you are considered to be in the app dir.

Comment: I tried and it still creates it in the app, also I am not in the root or src.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you have app/components/folder/
The command is :

```
ng g class components/folder/yourClassName
```

add --flat at the end if you don't want a folder created. You don't have to be in that folder, you can be in root folder of the app